# Bing api search results show different description

Tags: c#, api, search-engine, bing

I have an asp.net site and I'm trying to use the bing API with SOAP. When I get the results, the description field actually contains the meta description of the result page. Example: I send the query: "site:gamespot.com crysis release dates" and the descriptions field is "Crysis is a Sci-Fi FPS game for the PC in which mankind must struggle to survive in the face of an alien invasion" which is actually the meta description of the page the result is pointing to.

But for the same query directly written on bing.com the links have descriptions like:
"Crysis for PC Video Game Information - GameSpot's Crysis Technical Information, Game Information, and ... Release Date: Nov 13, 2007 ESRB: MATURE ESRB Descriptors: Blood, Strong" 
It actually writes the context of the searched words.

So why does the API behaves different? I want my custom search to also show the context in which the words are found. 
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It has been noted by Microsoft in the Bing API forums that results from the API are or can differ from a standard bing.com search.

The thread below was followed up on by the bing search api team.

http://www.bing.com/community/developer/f/12254/p/667751/9650589.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Way you specify your Query.

Query Should be like:

request.query = "crysis release dates (site:gamespot.com)"

Comment: sorry, that doesn't seem to work. It's not the problem with the results but with what it shows as their description. It's funny because there is an option to highlight searched words but this is useless because rarely the words are in the meta-description.